# How to Transfer NSData in UDP?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, udp, nsdata, avcapturesession

I have been working on video chat application, We have developed same app for windows and android also, Now I am trying to do for IOS and communicate between those. For that I have captured raw video data through this delegate...

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

now I want to use socket and transfer the raw data through network.

```
        UIImage *temp_image = [self getUIImageFromBuffer:sampleBuffer];
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(temp_image, 1.0);

        const void *bytes = [data bytes];

udp_obj->send_packet((char*)bytes, size, "30.0.0.104", 2030);
```

where udp_obj is a c++ udp class.

I have been using this bytes as raw data to transfer through UDP, Am I doing right here. Other end packets are receiving but each and every packets are looks same, I am not sure Am I going in right direction. Can anyone guide me... 
thanks.

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track but you'll have to post the code where you actually send the data.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I have sent like above, do u have any idea in other end wire shark is showing same kind of data for all my loopback calls, Is it possible?

Comment: data_size = [data length]; using this data_size i'm sending 960(size) bytes at a time, so size will be 960,960..... least value at last.

Comment: wait the data is only 960 bytes? that can't be right, not for a compressed frame of video. EDIT: Anyways, the basic idea is you call `[NSData bytes]` and then send that buffer (with size `[NSData length]`. So you're doing that part right. Without more context though, not much more I can go on.

Comment: no data is more than 960 bytes but my udp class at max only sent 960byte at time so I have done packetization 960byte at a time, it will loop and complete one frames.. and will process next frame.

Comment: Ok man I'm happy I'm going right path, thanks I will try it out from here on.. :)

Comment: good luck! When you solve it post back here to let us know how you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code worked fine. If anyone want to send raw data through UDP, you can follow this.